# ckeditor highlighting content of div and deleting also deletes the div

Tags: ckeditor, kentico

I use the templates plugin for my ckeditor and I input a 2 column structure like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="two_col half">
        <p>Info Block One. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et m. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="two_col half">
        <p>Info Block Two. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et m. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My content editors then edit the content of each div and input whatever text they need to.
The issue I'm having is that when my editors highlight the lorem ipsum text and delete it to start their content, the delete action also deletes the actual div itself, resulting in this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="two_col half">
        <p>Info Block One. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et m. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I can do to stop that from happening, I would like the div to remain after the user deletes the lorem ipsum placeholder text.

I'm using version 4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prevent it from the CK Editor perspective, but from Kentico point of view, you can style the template to have two Editable texts next to each other for those two columns. You can either have two web part zones - one editable text per each or two texts in one zone.

Comment: I use the templates plugin for my ckeditor specifically to give my writers the options to design their article content however they like. Either with a 2 column text or even a 3 column, or having an image to the left with text or an image to the right, etc. So I dont want to put that into my Kentico Page Template because then it would be set in stone that everyone has to use the 2 columns.